# Ubuntu 14.04 unknown monitor and wrong max. resolution

Tags: ubuntu, display, resolution

Nvidia GeForce 8800GT

Drivers installed

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current nvidia-settings
```

Display: AOC e2343Fk (1920x1080)

System Settings: Unknown Display, max resolution 1360x768

I've tried

1)

> sudo cvt 1920 1080 60

```
*1920x1080 59.96 Hz (CVT 2.07M9) hsync: 67.16 kHz; pclk: 173.00 MHz
Modeline "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync*
```

> sudo xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
>
> sudo xrandr -q
>   Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1360 x 768, maximum 8192 x 8192

DVI-I-0 connected primary 1360x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768       60.0 +
   1360x768       60.0*    59.8
   1152x864       60.0
   800x600        72.2     60.3     56.2
   680x384        60.0     59.8
   640x480        59.9
   512x384        60.0
   400x300        72.2
   320x240        60.1
DVI-I-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
TV-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

1920x1080_60.00 (0x2a2)  173.0MHz
        h: width  1920 start 2048 end 2248 total 2576 skew    0 clock   67.2KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1083 end 1088 total 1120           clock   60.0Hz

```
sudo xrandr --addmode DVI-I-0 1920x1080_60.00
```

**X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)**

Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)

Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)

Serial number of failed request:  31

Current serial number in output stream:  32

2)

```
xrandr --fb 1920x1080 -d DVI-I-0
```

*Can't open display DVI-I-0*

3) Persistent conf

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-monitor.conf


Section "Monitor"  
  Identifier "Monitor0"
  Modeline "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
EndSection  

Section "Screen"  
  Identifier "Screen0"
  Device "DVI-I-0"
  Monitor "Monitor0"
  DefaultDepth 24
  Option "DVI-I-0" "Monitor0"
  SubSection "Display"
    Depth 24
    Modes "1920x1080_60.00" "1360x768" "1024x768"
  EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using dual monitors but I kept only that 1920x1080 one to make the tests.
I resolved the issue adding HorizSync and VertRefresh values in /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-monitor.conf

```
Section "Monitor"  
  Identifier "Monitor0"
  Modeline "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
  HorizSync       30.0 - 83.0
  VertRefresh     50.0 - 75.0  
EndSection
```

I copied and pasted those values from [here](https://books.google.com.uy/books?id=Rv7zBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA288&lpg=PA288&dq=aoc%20e2343fk%20HorizSync%20%20%20%20%20%20VertRefresh&source=bl&ots=HHlU_AUYGo&sig=G0xuNulisPX8b39IO31zoWtb21s&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=aoc%20e2343fk%20HorizSync%20%20%20%20%20%20VertRefresh&f=false) according to my monitor

After enabling the second monitor I didn't have problems in any of both